# I want to install 64bit ubuntu onto my computer currently running 32bit ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

I have a viglen genie computer with an intel core 2 duo and 4gbs of ram and it can run 64bit. I currently have 32bit ubuntu and have just found out that chrome will no longer be supported on this and I need chrome. So can I just install 64bit ubuntu from the website and will it work? Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 64-bit Ubuntu will work on your computer. Intel Core 2 Duo processors support the 64-bit architecture, and 4GB RAM is enough memory to make installing Ubuntu 64-bit give improved performance.